# custom endpoint metadata in app.config file

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, app-config

I've got a app.config file for my application which defines a series of web services similar to this:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxxxxx.local:12610/Applicationws.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test1"
          contract="Applicationws.Applicationws" name="test1" />

        <endpoint address="https://yyyyyy.local:12610/Applicationws.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test2"
            contract="Applicationws.Applicationws" name="test2" />

        <endpoint address="https://zzzzzz.local:12610/Applicationws.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test3"
            contract="Applicationws.Applicationws" name="test3" />
</client>
```

I'd like to be able to add some extra attributes to each endpoint entry so I can easily identify it. These would be items such as Description, Type etc. and then be able to get this back in the ChannelEndpointElement object or similar e.g.

```
<endpoint address="https://zzzzzz.local:12610/Applicationws.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test3"
    ontract="Applicationws.Applicationws" name="test3"
    description="some web service" type="myappname" />
```

I've had a nose around the net and tried reading the docs but I cannot find anything close. Is it really such an unreasonable thing to want to do? My final thought is to append the extra attributes to the name value with a separator of some kind.

Comment: Additional information can go to comments, `<!-- additional information -->`

Comment: Can you tell me, do you want these attributes just for reference purpose???? If it is for reference purpose then you can put into comments..

Comment: Comments are not suitable as the extra metadata is not just for reference purposes. I'm going to display a window with a list of the services and I wanted to have a friendly description for each one. The user will then select which service they want to use.